# "ValueError: Structure is a scalar but len(flat_sequence) == 0 > 1" when saving Keras model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to save a Keras model that consists of two other Keras models ensembled. I'm using keras==2.3.1 and tensorflow==2.0.0 on Python 3.7.

```
    text_in = tensorflow.keras.layers.Input(shape=(MAX_SEQ_LEN,), dtype="int32", name='myinput')
    mods = [model_0, model_1]
    model_outputs = [model(text_in) for model in mods]
    ensemble_output = tf.keras.layers.Average()(model_outputs)
    ensemble_model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=text_in, outputs=ensemble_output)
```

When I do `ensemble_model.save(fname)`, I get the following traceback.

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-65-0212c05a2372> in <module>
      1 fname = 'model_multiclass_multilabel_{}.h5'.format(datetime.utcnow())
      2 base = fname.split('.h5')[0]
----> 3 model.save(fname)

/opt/miniconda3/envs/ml/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/network.py in save(self, filepath, overwrite, include_optimizer, save_format, signatures, options)
    973     """
    974     saving.save_model(self, filepath, overwrite, include_optimizer, save_format,
--> 975                       signatures, options)
    976 
    977   def save_weights(self, filepath, overwrite=True, save_format=None):

/opt/miniconda3/envs/ml/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/saving/save.py in save_model(model, filepath, overwrite, include_optimizer, save_format, signatures, options)
    110           'or using `save_weights`.')
    111     hdf5_format.save_model_to_hdf5(
--> 112         model, filepath, overwrite, include_optimizer)
    113   else:
    114     saved_model_save.save(model, filepath, overwrite, include_optimizer,

/opt/miniconda3/envs/ml/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/saving/hdf5_format.py in save_model_to_hdf5(model, filepath, overwrite, include_optimizer)
     97 
     98   try:
---> 99     model_metadata = saving_utils.model_metadata(model, include_optimizer)
    100     for k, v in model_metadata.items():
    101       if isinstance(v, (dict, list, tuple)):

/opt/miniconda3/envs/ml/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/saving/saving_utils.py in model_metadata(model, include_optimizer, require_config)
    160   model_config = {'class_name': model.__class__.__name__}
    161   try:
--> 162     model_config['config'] = model.get_config()
    163   except NotImplementedError as e:
    164     if require_config:

/opt/miniconda3/envs/ml/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/network.py in get_config(self)
    885     if not self._is_graph_network:
    886       raise NotImplementedError
--> 887     return copy.deepcopy(get_network_config(self))
    888 
    889   @classmethod

/opt/miniconda3/envs/ml/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/network.py in get_network_config(network, serialize_layer_fn)
   1940           filtered_inbound_nodes.append(node_data)
   1941 
-> 1942     layer_config = serialize_layer_fn(layer)
   1943     layer_config['name'] = layer.name
   1944     layer_config['inbound_nodes'] = filtered_inbound_nodes

/opt/miniconda3/envs/ml/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/utils/generic_utils.py in serialize_keras_object(instance)
    138   if hasattr(instance, 'get_config'):
    139     return serialize_keras_class_and_config(instance.__class__.__name__,
--> 140                                             instance.get_config())
    141   if hasattr(instance, '__name__'):
    142     return instance.__name__

/opt/miniconda3/envs/ml/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/network.py in get_config(self)
    885     if not self._is_graph_network:
    886       raise NotImplementedError
--> 887     return copy.deepcopy(get_network_config(self))
    888 
    889   @classmethod

/opt/miniconda3/envs/ml/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/network.py in get_network_config(network, serialize_layer_fn)
   1956     model_inputs.append(
   1957         tf_utils.ListWrapper([layer.name, new_node_index, tensor_index]))
-> 1958   model_inputs = nest.pack_sequence_as(network._nested_inputs, model_inputs)
   1959   # Preserve external Keras compat for Models with single input.
   1960   if not nest.is_sequence(model_inputs):

/opt/miniconda3/envs/ml/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/util/nest.py in pack_sequence_as(structure, flat_sequence, expand_composites)
    454     if len(flat_sequence) != 1:
    455       raise ValueError("Structure is a scalar but len(flat_sequence) == %d > 1"
--> 456                        % len(flat_sequence))
    457     return flat_sequence[0]
    458 

ValueError: Structure is a scalar but len(flat_sequence) == 0 > 1
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I've made sure the models were all trained using the same version of Keras/TF and they all share the same types of inputs.

Any idea how I can save this model properly?

Comment: Cannot reproduce your error with TF 2.0, can you post all your models